# Using latest Less CSS version on Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, twitter-bootstrap, less

I have Lessc working on Ubuntu 12.10, through apt-get, but it is version 1.3 - I can't compile Bootstrap and I think need 1.3.3.

Does anybody know how to get 1.3.3 working on Ubuntu?

Answer (score 1):

You can install [node.js](http://nodejs.org/) and then install the latest less using `npm`:

```
sudo apt-get install nodejs
sudo npm install -g less
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer - I get the following error:

'module.js:340
    throw err;
          ^
    Error: Cannot find module 'less'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:338:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:280:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:362:17)
    at require (module.js:378:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/bin/lessc:8:12)
    at Module._compile (module.js:449:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:467:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
    at Module.runMain (module.js:492:10)'

Comment: @Staple try to install it like this then: http://askubuntu.com/questions/49390/how-do-i-install-the-latest-version-of-node-js and the run the `npm install...`

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I updated the PPA but it said I was already running newest nodejs - still getting that error (as above)